# ENOTFOUND with typings install (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, npm, typescript-typings

I'm using [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) in one of my TypeScript projects. I'm having a problem when running the command to install type definitions:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/typings install
typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "angular". You should check the entry paths in "angular.d.ts" are up to date
typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7ce80dafc0df189d61950e80e04548d8304d1538/angularjs/angular.d.ts"
typings ERR! caused by getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND raw.githubusercontent.com raw.githubusercontent.com:443
```

It would seem that it can't get angular.d.ts (ENOTFOUND). But I'm confused by this, because I can get that just fine with curl:

```
$ curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7ce80dafc0df189d61950e80e04548d8304d1538/angularjs/angular.d.ts"
// Type definitions for Angular JS 1.4+
// Project: http://angularjs.org
. . .
```

Any ideas? Why is typings/node not able to find the type defs?

```
Node 6.3.0
Typings 1.3.2
npm 3.10.5
```

---

**EDIT**

I made a simple node script to try to reproduce the problem. Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce it - this script works fine, even though `typings install` consistently produces the error.

```
var https = require('https');
var options = {
    host: 'raw.githubusercontent.com',
    path: '/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7ce80dafc0df189d61950e80e04548d8304d1538/angularjs/angular.d.ts',
    port: 443
};

var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
    var str = '';
    console.log(options.host + ':' + res.statusCode);

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        str += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(str);
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('ERROR! ' + err);
});
```

---

**EDIT 2**

wget fails with an error about a certificate. Not sure if this is at all related:

```
$ wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7ce80dafc0df189d61950e80e04548d8304d1538/angularjs/angular.d.ts"
--2016-08-16 20:00:13--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7ce80dafc0df189d61950e80e04548d8304d1538/angularjs/angular.d.ts
Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com... 151.101.48.133
Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com|151.101.48.133|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name “www.github.com” doesn’t match requested host name “raw.githubusercontent.com”.
To connect to raw.githubusercontent.com insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

Comment: Are you connecting via a proxy?

Comment: No. I am on a corporate network though (behind a firewall).

Comment: Also, this used to work just fine. Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly when it stopped working or what changed to make it stop working.

Comment: I have a workaround! I can get the IP address with `ping raw.githubusercontent.com`. If I put that in my `/etc/hosts` file, everything works great. Still not sure exactly what the cause is, but I'm starting to suspect perhaps something related to IPv6...

Comment: I don't see anything here that would suggest IPv6 is relevant in any way. If you have something, please edit your question to include it.